# How to avoid cyclic import in this case?

Tags: python

**models.py:**

```
from core.tasks import hello 

class Foo(models.Model):
    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None, update_fields=None):
        hello.delay()
        super(Foo, self).save(force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
```

**tasks.py:**

```
from core.models import Foo

@shared_task
def hello():
    Foo.objects.create()
```

Code above causes `ImportError: cannot import name Foo`.

How to avoid this situations and follow best practices?

Comment: You can always import at function level.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: import at function level means?

Comment: It might mean that it's possible to move the import statement into the function definition below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either import the model at function level:

```
@shared_task
def hello():
    from core.models import Foo
    Foo.objects.create()
```

Or You can use django's [`get_model()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.get_model) function to import models in a more clean way:

```
from django.apps import apps

@shared_task
def hello():
    foo_model = apps.get_model('core', 'Foo')
    # 'core' is appname and 'Foo' is model name
    foo_model.objects.create()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can import inside of the functions, and that will make you code work:

```
@shared_task
def hello():
    from core.models import Foo
    Foo.objects.create()
```

However, 99% of the times I ran into this problem I realized that there was a logical error in my code after thinking hard enough. Disclaimer: I have almost no experience with django.

If `A` needs `B` and `B` needs `A`, there is generally something broken. Most of the times, the problem is one of these:

- `A` and `B` logically belong toghether and should be merged into the same module
- `A` and `B` are logically discting enough, but there is common functionality that does not depend on anything else from `A` or `B`, making it possible to abstract it into `C` and import it from the other two.
- `A` has a fake dependency into `B`, because `A` does not need `B` at all.

In your case, I would say that it is the third option. `tasks` clearly needs to rely on `models`. But does `models` need `tasks` at all? just do from `models` what you need. For instance:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None, update_fields=None):
        Foo.objects.create()
        super(Foo, self).save(force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
```

Comment: tasks.py have more complicated code and logic - `Foo.objects.create()` only for example

Comment: You can try to pack your code into a method, for instance `Foo.do_the_complicated_thing`, and then call it from the `tasks`.